# Placing trigger order on FTX future market via Rest API fails

Tags: c#, api, cryptocurrency

1. I'm trying to place trigger orders in FTX Future BTC-PERP, without any success, for any combination of side / order type / trigger price and price
2. all placements fails . The attached image show the results of all combination.

[image]
3. I have no issues to place "non trigger" order.

4. similar orders placed via the website are placed successfully
5. market price  at the time of tries +-20000
6. sample request sent:

**For the first case in the image**

```
{"market": "BTC-PERP","side": "buy","size": "0.0001","type": "stop","triggerPrice": "21000","retryUntilFilled": "False"}
```

**For the second case in the image**

```
{"market": "BTC-PERP","side": "buy","size": "0.0001","type": "stop","triggerPrice": "21000","retryUntilFilled": "False","orderPrice": "21500"}
```

7. Developed in C#

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

FTX will not accept a maker order on BTC-Perp for a size of less than 0.001

https://help.ftx.com/hc/en-us/articles/360027946651-Order-Limits-and-Price-Bands